# Facebook sharing dialogue cancel button doesn't window close

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, facebook-social-plugins

I have a facebook share button setup with this event and url:

```
window.open('https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id={{myid}}&display=popup&' +
      'link={{my url}}&redirect_uri={{my url again}}', 'The title', 'resizable,height=400,width=550');
```

My issue is when I click cancel, instead of closing my open window, the user is directed to {{my url}} (the same url as {{my url again}}

What am I missing?

Comment: _“What am I missing?”_ – only that this is exactly how it is supposed to work. If you want that popup window, that you yourself opened, to be closed again, then you have to do that yourself as well – from within the page that gets redirected to after posting. Or, instead of opening your own popup, you could use the JS SDK, method `FB.ui` to present the dialog – that will take care of closing it again itself.

Comment: @CBroe How do you close a window that way? The url that is opened is a Facebook url. You can't self-close a tab, can you, unless you've opened the window yourself. Since I'm opening a window that goes to an external url, I'm not sure how I could detect behavior within that off-domain url.

Comment: _“The url that is opened is a Facebook url”_ … from which the user will be redirected back to your app, after they confirmed (or canceled) the login dialog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I  ended up using:

```
if (window.location.hash == '#_=_') {
        open(location, '_self').close();
}
```

Not the best solution, I don't think. The hash location is the url the Facebook cancel button directs from.